# Get ASP.NET MVC model field's description from annotation

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Say, I have an MVC model

```
public class MyModel
{
    [Display(Name = "Sophistically-named field", Description = "blah-blah")]
    public int SophisticallyNamedField {get;set;}
}
```

Is there any way I can get field's name and description from annotation? I need to get it in C# code, not in Razor.

Comment: Is this in code in a Controller?

Comment: Duplication: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7027613/how-to-retrieve-data-annotations-from-code-programmatically.

Comment: @FatAlbert, Andrei
I see. Wasn't able to google them up, though. Voted to close the question. Don't want to delete it, will prove useful in finding info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Reflection to access the values of a given Attribute. You might want to check out the [GetCustomAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k7s8054x%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method or have a look at [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2656189/how-do-i-read-an-attribute-on-a-class-at-runtime) of the [countless](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3289198/custom-attribute-on-property-getting-type-and-value-of-attributed-property) samples on this site.