# Am I missing a using to use [Display(Name = "string")] on an enum?

Tags: c#, enums, displayname-attribute

"The type or namespace name Display cannot be found ... "
"The type or namespace name Name cannot be found ... "

```
public enum MyEnum
{
  [Display(Name = "The First")]
  first = 1,
  [Display(Name = "The Second")]
  second,
  [Display(Name = "The Third")]
  third= 1
}
```

I tried `[DisplayName("The First")]` and that is only valid for a Class, Method Property, or Event...

What am I missing here?

UDPATE: Needed `[Description()]` so...

```
public enum MyEnum
{
  [Description("The First")]
  first = 1,
  [Description("The Second")]
  second,
  [Description("The Third")]
  third= 1
}
```

Comment: Check my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3289198/custom-attribute-on-property-getting-type-and-value-of-attributed-property/49560324#49560324

Comment: Sounds like you're missing a `using`... Or you may want to use [`Description`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1799370/215552)...

Comment: `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations`?

Comment: Yes.  You are looking for the DisplayAttribute class.  Using "Attribute" is optional in C#.

Comment: [Description] ... that was it. SMH. Thank you all!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If someone ends up here because they *are* looking for the [DisplayAttribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.displayattribute?view=netframework-4.7.2), it lives in the `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations` namespace. What makes things confusing is that you can add a `using` directive for this particular namespace, and it won't complain... but it won't find `DisplayAttribute` either. It stays greyed out as if the directive is unnecessary.

[image]

Right-click on *"References"* in your project and select *"System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations"*.

The `using` directive will turn black, and the `Display` attribute will be recognized.

[image]

Comment: Good point here. This was not my particular need. However, I'm going to accept this answer as I do believe others who come here will likely need this info.

Answer (score -1):

You might wanna use Description.

```
public enum MyEnum
{
  [Description(Name = "The First")]
  first = 1,
  [Description(Name = "The Second")]
  second =2,
  [DisDescriptionplay(Name = "The Third")]
  third= 1
}
```